# Generating file to download with Django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to make a zip archive and offer it to download, but still not save a file to the hard drive?

Comment: There is a code example at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/

Answer (score 118):

To trigger a download you need to set `Content-Disposition` header:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

# generate the file
response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(myfile.getvalue()), content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.zip'
return response
```

If you don't want the file on disk you need to use `StringIO`

```
import cStringIO as StringIO

myfile = StringIO.StringIO()
while not_finished:
    # generate chunk
    myfile.write(chunk)
```

Optionally you can set `Content-Length` header as well:

```
response['Content-Length'] = myfile.tell()
```

Comment: I think Content-Length might happen automatically with Django middleware

Comment: Using this example downloads a file that is always empty, any ideas?

Comment: As @eleaz28 said, it was creating blank files in my case too. I just removed the `FileWrapper`, and it worked.

Comment: This answer doesn't work with Django 1.9: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35485073/375966

Comment: I know this post is old now, but @eleaz28, i was having the same trouble, i solved it by using fileIO.seek(0).

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani, to only download file in django 1.10 there's a documentation now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

Comment: I opened my file in read mode then file.getvalue() is giving attribute error : TextIOWrapper has no attribute getValue .

Comment: New versions of Django provide FileResponse which is a wrapper around wsgiref FileWrapper but generates streaming http response: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

Answer (score 28):

You'll be happier creating a temporary file.  This saves a lot of memory.  When you have more than one or two users concurrently, you'll find the memory saving is very, very important.

You can, however, write to a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) object.

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> import StringIO
>>> buffer= StringIO.StringIO()
>>> z= zipfile.ZipFile( buffer, "w" )
>>> z.write( "idletest" )
>>> z.close()
>>> len(buffer.getvalue())
778
```

The "buffer" object is file-like with a 778 byte ZIP archive.

Comment: Good point about saving memory. But if using a temporary file, where would you put the code to delete it?

Comment: @superjoe30: periodical cleanup jobs.  Django already has an admin command that must be run periodically to remove old sessions.

Comment: @superjoe30 that's what /tmp is for :)

Comment: @S.Lott Is it possible to serve  the created file (z in in your example) using mod x-sendfile?

Answer (score 11):

Why not make a tar file instead? Like so:

```
def downloadLogs(req, dir):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/x-gzip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=download.tar.gz'
    tarred = tarfile.open(fileobj=response, mode='w:gz')
    tarred.add(dir)
    tarred.close()

    return response
```

Comment: For newer version of Django, you should have `content_type=` instead of `mimetype=`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use the [zipfile module](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/zipfile-objects.html), [zlib module](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-zlib.html) or other [compression modules](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/archiving.html) to create a zip archive in memory.  You can make your view write the zip archive to the `HttpResponse` object that the Django view returns instead of sending a context to a template.  Lastly, you'll need to set the mimetype to the appropriate format to [tell the browser to treat the response as a file](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment).

Answer (score 7):

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class PageHeader(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
```

#### views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from StringIO import StringIO
from models import *
import os, mimetypes, urllib

def random_header_image(request):
    header = PageHeader.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    image = StringIO(file(header.image.path, "rb").read())
    mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(os.path.basename(header.image.name))[0]

    return HttpResponse(image.read(), mimetype=mimetype)
```

Comment: Looks unsafe to create in-memory string of image size.

Answer (score 5):

```
def download_zip(request,file_name):
    filePath = '<path>/'+file_name
    fsock = open(file_name_with_path,"rb")
    response = HttpResponse(fsock, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.zip'
    return response
```

You can replace zip and content type as per your requirement.

Comment: You meant `fsock = open(filePath,"rb")`

Answer (score 4):

Same with in memory tgz archive:

```
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO


def serve_file(request):
    out = BytesIO()
    tar = tarfile.open(mode = "w:gz", fileobj = out)
    data = 'lala'.encode('utf-8')
    file = BytesIO(data)
    info = tarfile.TarInfo(name="1.txt")
    info.size = len(data)
    tar.addfile(tarinfo=info, fileobj=file)
    tar.close()

    response = HttpResponse(out.getvalue(), content_type='application/tgz')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.tgz'
    return response
```