# Django user-specific files (browse, download)

Tags: django, django-permissions, file-browser

I have a situation where I have a Django app where users sign up for an account. The users generate a bunch of Excel files each month. These files are currently simply files generated on the server and stored in the filesystem, and are not part of any model definition right now, though I could probably change that to have them defined in a model, and use together with user permissions.

The app is working as expected, but I am stuck on how to let users browse and download their own generated files, while disallowing access to other users' files.

I was looking at django-filer, but am wondering if anybody has met with this situation before?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a `FileField`, a FK or M2M to `User` or `Group`, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908258/generating-file-to-download-with-django).

Comment: It's a good tip to create an archive and offer it for download. My downloads are working. What I meant was I want to allow the user to come back at a later date so that they can browse their own files and download them if they want, like a file browser with django permissions I guess.

Comment: As I implied, stick all the files in a table and use the FK or M2M to determine who can see which files.