# Python: Create and return an SQLite DB as a web request result

Tags: python, django, sqlite

In my python/django based web application I want to export some (not all!) data from the app's SQLite database to a new SQLite database file and, in a web request, return that second SQLite file as a downloadable file.

In other words: The user visits some view and, internally, a new SQLite DB file is created, populated with data and then returned.

Now, although I know about the `:memory:` magic for creating an SQLite DB in memory, I don't know how to return that in-memory database as a downloadable file in the web request. Could you give me some hints on how I could reach that? I would like to avoid writing stuff to the disc during the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get at the contents of a `:memory:` database to treat it as a file; a quick look through the SQLite documentation suggests that its API doesn't expose the `:memory:` database to you as a binary string, or a memory-mapped file, or any other way you could access it as a series of bytes. The only way to access a `:memory:` database is through the SQLite API.

What I would do in your shoes is to set up your server to have a directory mounted with `ramfs`, then create an SQLite3 database as a "file" in that directory. When you're done populating the database, return that "file", then delete it. This will be the simplest solution by far: you'll avoid having to write anything to disk and you'll gain the same speed benefits as using a `:memory:` database, but your code will be much easier to write.

Comment: Hi rmunn, thank you for the answer. In fact, I can as well just use `/tmp/some_db.sqlite` and delete it afterwards. Although it would have been nicer to do it in memory only, that is ok for me.

Comment: That *would* be in memory only. :-) If you meant to say "I want to avoid writing to the filesystem" rather than "I want to avoid writing to the *disk*", then your word choice in your question failed to communicate that. :-)

Comment: If you're thinking that it would be more "elegant" to build the database in memory rather than writing a temporary file to /tmp and returning it, then I suggest you're valuing "elegance" too highly over code simplicity and maintainability. Writing temporary files to /tmp is fine; that's what it's there for! And more importantly, if you use the "write a temporary file to /tmp" method, when you come back to this code six months or a year from now, you'll *still know what it does*. That's a quality that should not be underestimated.

Comment: I solved it with the /tmp method. Thank you for you thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

With web content you can easily serve files as raw binary with a content type specified in the response.

Django makes this fairly easy - here's a snippet I use on one of my sites for generating a barcode for a user.

```
def barcode(request):
    from core import ugbarcode
    bar = ugbarcode.UGBar("0001")
    binStream = bar.asString('gif')
    return HttpResponse(binStream, 'image/gif')
```

See also this post for more details in specifying it is an attachment to trigger download: [Generating file to download with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908258/generating-file-to-download-with-django)

Comment: Thank you, that helped me already. Now, how to get the sqlite file from `conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")` or `conn = sqlite3.connect("")` (the latter creates a database file in memory)?