# Serve a file for download with Django

Tags: python, django, download

I am trying to serve a download file in my django app, after a bit of research I made the code below but there is one problem, the file is opened in the browser instead of being downloaded.

The files that I serve on my app are exe, and when they open it's just a bunch of random characters.

So how can I specify that I want the file to be downloaded, not opened? 
Thank you

```
with open(path_to_apk, 'rb') as fh:
     response = HttpResponse(fh)
     response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(path_to_apk)
     return response`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating file to download with Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908258/generating-file-to-download-with-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the Content-disposition header to "attachment" (and set the proper content-type too - from the var names I assume those files are android packages, else replace with the proper content type):

```
response = HttpResponse(fh, content_type="application/vnd.android.package-archive") 
response["Content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename={}".format(os.path.basename(path_to_apk))
return response
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working, there is a misspelling on the code: instead of format you wrote fomat, maybe you can correct it for others who might want to use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set the `Content_Disposition` header to `attachment`.

And instead of worrying about correct value for `Content_Type` header, use [**FileResponse**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects)
instead of **HttpResponse**:

```
file=open(path_to_apk,"rb")
response=FileResponse(file)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(os.path.basename(path_to_apk))
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) with `as_attachment=True` for this. It will handle stuff like reading the file into memory, setting the correct `Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition`, etc. automatically for you.

```py
from django.http import FileResponse

def download_file(request):
    return FileResponse(open(path_to_apk, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
```